# nginx proxy based on username

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I'm using nginx as a proxy server in front of Tomcat instances.

There's basic authentication set up, giving access to the demo page just to a few users.

Is it possible to modify the proxy_pass parameter depending on the username provided by the client ?

Basically, if user1, user2, proxy http://host:1234, if user3, user4, proxy http://host:4321.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [$remote_user](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24remote_user) variable with [Map module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) to set proxy port.